# Conditional routes not working in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I want to allow routes only if the user has the appropriate role to visit them. I do the check both on the frontend and the backend, however when using `Switch` something is not working.

```
 {localStorage.getItem("roles") && localStorage.getItem("roles").split(",").includes("CONTRIBUTOR") &&
              <>
                {/* Contributor Routes */}
                <Route exact path="/contributor/upload" component={ContributorUploadPage}/>
                <Route exact path="/contributor/edit/:rawContentId" component={ContributorEditPage}/>
                <Route exact path="/contributor" component={ContributorListPage}/>
               </> }

              {localStorage.getItem("roles") && localStorage.getItem("roles").split(",").includes("EDITOR") &&
                //{/* Editor Routes */}
                <>
                <Route exact path="/editor/search" component={EditorSearch}/>
                <Route path="/editor/upload" component={EditorUploadPage}/>
                <Route exact path="/editor/edit/:finalContentId" component={EditorEditPage}/>
                <Route exact path="/editor" component={EditorListPage}/>
                </>
              }

              {localStorage.getItem("roles") && localStorage.getItem("roles").split(",").map(item => (item === "SUB_PERVIEW" || item === "SUB_SUBSCRIPTION" 
              || item === "SUB_FREE" ? true : false)) &&
              <>
                {/* Subscriber Routes */}
                <Route exact path="/content" component={ContentPage}/>
              </> }

<Route path="/404" component={NotFoundPage}/>
              <Redirect to="/404"/>
```

If I now go to `/editor`, even if I don't have an appropriate role, I'm not being redirected to `/404`. If I remove all of the conditions, the `/404` page is rendered.

Comment: You should not gate the `<Route />` itself but instead create all of the routes and then call a function within each component to check if a user has permission to visit that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply define a protected route component and reuse it:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const isContributor = localStorage.getItem("roles") && localStorage.getItem("roles").split(",").includes("CONTRIBUTOR");

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isContributor ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/404" />
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Then use that route as follows:

```js
 <ProtectedRoute exact path="/editor" component={EditorListPage}/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to check what component is passed to the ProtectedRoute function? For example, 
`<Route exact path="/content" component={ContentPage}/>`, can I get the path inside of the `ProtectedRoute` function so I can compare the role? Or do I need separate functions for every role?

Comment: Sure. In `ProtectedRoute` function, that `rest` param has all props for that route. If you try `console.log(rest)` you'll find that it has three main objects: `path`, `computedMatch`, and `location`

Comment: I also like the idea of creating a custom route component (almost added it to my answer), though I suggest exposing out an `allowedRole` callback function (to use in place of your `isContributor` check or simply passing an array of acceptable roles, that allows the role check to be defined where the `ProtectedRoute` is used. This way you won't need to define a protected route for each type of role access is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Only `Route` or `Redirect` are valid children of the `Switch` component, the React fragments are being returned and messing with the route matching.

You can place a `Route` around each "group" or sub-route area you want to conditionally render. The "trick" is to return the grouped sub-routes within another switch for matching.

I also suggest factoring out the getting of roles into a utility function to make your code more **DRY**.

```
const getRoles = () => (localStorage.getItem("roles") || '').split(",");

...

<Switch>
  {/* Contributor Routes */}
  {getRoles().includes("CONTRIBUTOR") && (
    <Route path="/contributor">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/contributor/upload" component={ContributorUploadPage}/>
        <Route path="/contributor/edit/:rawContentId" component={ContributorEditPage}/>
        <Route path="/contributor" component={ContributorListPage}/>
      </Switch>
    </Route>
  )}

  {/* Editor Routes */}
  {getRoles().includes("EDITOR") && (
    <Route path="/editor">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/editor/search" component={EditorSearch}/>
        <Route path="/editor/upload" component={EditorUploadPage}/>
        <Route path="/editor/edit/:finalContentId" component={EditorEditPage}/>
        <Route path="/editor" component={EditorListPage}/>
      </Switch>
    </Route>
  )}
  
  {/* Subscriber Routes */}
  {getRoles.some(
     item => ["SUB_PERVIEW", "SUB_SUBSCRIPTION", "SUB_FREE"].includes(item)
   ) && (
    <Route path="/content" component={ContentPage}/>
  )}

  <Route path="/404" component={NotFoundPage}/>
  <Redirect to="/404"/>
</Switch>
```